# how to authenticate a web application contains multiple websites and databases on each sub directories?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

consider we have a domain and in root directory we are running laravel and in some subdirectories, we have other frameworks or cms with separated databases. for example in /blog ,there is a wordpress cms, in /shop , there is a woocommerce installation, in /ads, an express app exist and so on.
we can't develop a separated authentication for each one of them, because it's difficult for users to sign in multiple times in order to use all services of the domain.
so the question is what is the best way to have a single authentication method across all sub directories.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create a Universal Login (with Laravel or etc) to have single authentication method across all sub-directories but there are some platforms like: https://auth0.com/universal-login
and you can use them even for free!

Comment: can you please explain more about universal method that you have mentioned?

Comment: Because I code with laravel, I know  you can use laravel passport for Universal Login with OAuth.   You’d use Passport to allow the other applications to authenticate using OAuth. Your applications would then get an OAuth token (and user ID) when the user authenticates. You’d then need to use that user ID to either look up or create a user in your application’s database so you have a primary key to use in foreign keys. for more details: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/one-login-system-for-multiple-projects-1

Comment: it's good but as you might know, each framework and cms has its own session based authentication method. for example when we want to buy something from woocommerce, we should be logged in using wordpress session auth and the hard part is how all these can communicate with oauth like passport ? or am I missed something?

Comment: you are right but laravel let you share cookie (even session) with subdomains by some config in .env file.  So when a user logged in with laravel you will store some cookie and pass it to other domain as active user (authenticated user)...